# Laravel Carbon plus or minute one minute for comparing time

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I am working on a notification then checks every minute for a scheduled notification. It never calls it because my now variable is in a minute format (2021-01-28 10:27) where as the database send_date is stored (2021-01-28 10:15:11)

```
    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime(Carbon::now()));
    
   
    $notifications = Notification::get();
    if($notifications !== null)
    {
        Log::info('Notifications are not null ' .$now); // shows in log (2021-01-28 10:27)
        $notifications->where('send_date',  $now)->each(function($message) {
        Log::info('looking at send_date'); // never shows in log
        }
     }
```

Or is there another way of doing this, that I am not seeing?

Comment: You wanna check the exact time? or everything in this minute?

Comment: Everything in this minute

Comment: how about using whereBetween,  `$notifications->whereBetween('send_date', [Carbon::now()->subMinute(), Carbon::now()->addMinute()])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $notifications = Notification::get();
    if($notifications !== null)
    {
        Log::info('Notifications are not null ' .$now); // shows in log (2021-01-28 10:27)
        $notifications->whereBetween('send_date', [Carbon::now()->subMinute()->format('Y-m-d H:i'), Carbon::now()->addMinute()->format('Y-m-d H:i')])->each(function($message) {
            Log::info('looking at send_date'); // never shows in log
        }
     }
```

Reference : 
[whereBetween](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses), [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: This will fail because is missing seconds in the format

Comment: @diego182 when second format is not mentioned it is by default assumed as 00, this feature comes from DateTime class which is inherited by Carbon

Answer (score 2):

Then you could use the following way

```
    $notifications->whereBetween('send_date', [Carbon::now()->startOfMinute(), Carbon::now()->endOfMinute()])->each(function($message) {
```

If you need to format the time yourself then:

```
    $notifications->whereBetween('send_date', [Carbon::now()->startOfMinute()->format('Y-m-d H:I:s'), Carbon::now()->endOfMinute('Y-m-d H:I:s')])->each(function($message) {
```

Comment: Thank you, so very much for your help